# how to start the loop from the second post in blog page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I don't have much idea about wordpress. I have a blog in wordpress. In my blog page, i am showing the most recent post in top and rest of post will appear in bottom . I am getting the repitation of most recent blog in bottom as well. that means, it's appearing twice on page. I want to get rid it from bottom. Thanks
[image: design]

```html
<?php if (have_posts()):?>
<!-- section -->
<section>
<div class="row justify-content-center">
<div class="col-md-5"><?php $image1 = get_field('main_image');?>
  <img id="theImage" class="img-fluid" src="<?php echo $image1['url']; ?>" width="100%" height="auto" /></div>
<div class="col-md-4 base">
<div class="hero_col">
<p class="blog_content"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> </p>
<span class="head_blog_content">
 <?php 
  $thePostID = $wp_query->post->ID;
  echo get_post_meta($thePostID, 'blog_desc_content', true); ?>
</span>
<div class="read_article py-3"><a class="col btn-change" style="color: white;" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read Article</a></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="centered_cols"><span class="hero_text"><!-- post title -->
  <?php the_title(); ?>
  </span></div>
</div>
</section><!-- Gallery Section -->

<div class="product-container">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
 <?php $Number = 1; ?>
 <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 blog-container mb-3"><a href="#">
 <?php $image1 = get_field('main_image');?>
 <img src="<?php echo $image1['url']; ?>" width="100%" height="auto" /></a>
     <!-- post details -->
 <p class="blog_date"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></p>
 <span class="blog_caption"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
  </span>
  <p class="blog_content"><?php 
  $thePostID = $wp_query->post->ID;
  echo get_post_meta($thePostID, 'blog_desc_content', true); ?>
  </p>
    <div class="column-bottom"><span class="read_article">
    <a class="col btn-change" style="color: white;" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read Article</a></span></div>
</div>
  <!-- /post details -->
 <!-- article --> 
  <!-- post thumbnail -->
  <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if thumbnail exists ?>
   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(120,120)); // Declare pixel size you need inside the array ?>
   </a>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <!-- /post thumbnail -->

  <?php html5wp_excerpt('html5wp_index'); // Build your custom callback length in functions.php ?>
 <!-- /article -->

<?php $Number++;  endwhile; ?>

<?php else: ?>

 <!-- article -->
 <article>
  <h2><?php _e( 'Sorry, nothing to display.' ); ?></h2>
 </article>
 <!-- /article -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, since you don't know much about wordpress, its easier to create a counter to skip output in first item, something like this:

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 

$Number = 1; //initial value

if ($count != 1) : ?>
//all your post content here
<?php endif;

$Number++; // incrementing counter by 1
```

It seems you came up with the counting (I've set the var name as Number based on your code), you're just missing the conditional aparently.